# Uses of spectral radius equal to norm.

Tags: banach-algebras, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be a unital commutative Banach algebra.What can be the consequences of the spectral radius of an element $a$ equaling its norm $\|a\|$.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any interesting consequences offhand.

Now, assuming that the spectral radius of *every* element of $A$ is equal to the norm does have an interesting consequence - in fact it's easy to see that that condition is *equivalent* to saying $A$ is isometrically isomorphic to a closed subalgebra of $C(K)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $K$.

Comment: Thank you for this insight.